# Extending borders outward from div

Tags: html, css

I have tabs that are in a body tag in a popup:

[image]

```css
.tabs {

  width: 100%;

  height: 36px;

  font-size: 0;

}

.tabs .tab {

  width: 40%;

  height: 100%;

  padding: 7.5px 0 2px;

  display: inline-block;

  text-align: center;

  /* font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; */

  font-weight: 700;

  font-size: 12px;

  cursor: pointer;

}

.defaultselectedtab {

  border-top-style: solid;

  border-right-style: solid;

  border-left-style: solid;

  border-bottom-style: solid;

  border-top-color: black;

  border-right-color: black;

  border-left-color: black;

  border-bottom-color: gray;

}

.defaultnonselectedtab {

  border-top-style: solid;

  border-right-style: solid;

  border-left-style: solid;

  border-bottom-style: solid;

  border-top-color: gray;

  border-right-color: gray;

  border-left-color: gray;

  border-bottom-color: black;

}

#emailtabspacing {

  border-bottom-style: solid;

  border-bottom-color: black;

  padding: 0px 50px 27px 0px;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div id="emailtab1" class="tab defaultselectedtab">My Personal Message</div>
    <span id="emailtabspacing"></span>
    <div id="emailtab2" class="tab defaultnonselectedtab">Anonymous Message</div>
  </div>
```

How can I extend the boarders outward from the left and right of the div's to make the line hit the left and right of the body tag?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the bottom border to be at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I want the bottom border to extend out to the left and right of the boxes till it hits the end of the white area.

Comment: Ah, your question confused me by saying "make the line hit the end of the body tag" which I interpreted as the bottom/end of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the border from the left and right to the edge of the page (which I believe is what you want), add `border-bottom` to `.tabs`, and make sure `body` has no margin (see my code below). [Using a reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) will also help clear default browser CSS like this, and much more.

```css
body {
margin:0;
}

.tabs {

  width: 100%;

  height:36px;

  font-size: 0;
border-bottom:2px solid #000;

}

.tabs .tab {

  width: 40%;

  height: 100%;

  padding: 7.5px 0 2px;

  display: inline-block;

  text-align: center;

  /* font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; */

  font-weight: 700;

  font-size: 12px;

  cursor: pointer;

}

.defaultselectedtab {

  border-top-style: solid;

  border-right-style: solid;

  border-left-style: solid;

  border-bottom-style: solid;

  border-top-color: black;

  border-right-color: black;

  border-left-color: black;

  border-bottom-color: gray;

}

.defaultnonselectedtab {

  border-top-style: solid;

  border-right-style: solid;

  border-left-style: solid;

  border-bottom-style: solid;

  border-top-color: gray;

  border-right-color: gray;

  border-left-color: gray;

  border-bottom-color: black;

}

#emailtabspacing {

  border-bottom-style: solid;

  border-bottom-color: black;

  padding: 0px 50px 27px 0px;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div id="emailtab1" class="tab defaultselectedtab">My Personal Message</div>
    <span id="emailtabspacing"></span>
    <div id="emailtab2" class="tab defaultnonselectedtab">Anonymous Message</div>
  </div>
```